# hood.ie setting a fixed URL instead of network address

Tags: hoodie

I've made a hood.ie app, where I will be using 2 devices (a laptop from where i do `hoodie start`) and an iPad.

At the moment, on the iPad i need to get the network address from the laptop from where the app actually sits to enter it in Safari on the iPad (this can also change depending on whats connected to the wifi network).

Is there a more convenient way to do this as the app has be started and logged into daily?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, it's also not really part of Hoodie's scope. If you want to expose your local sever with less hassle, you could:

1. Give it a fixed IP address and just bookmark that on the ipad
2. Use a service like https://ngrok.com/ or http://localtunnel.me/ (especially the former) to have nicer or even fixed urls that tunnel through to your local server

Hope that helps!